# selectlist not triggering page reload for Watir and IE

Tags: internet-explorer, watir

same problem that was described in this post [Watir question regarding select_list and reloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877367/watir-question-regarding-select-list-and-reloading) but the solution is not working for me.

Setup is IE8, Watir 1.67.  I have automation that selects a value from a dropdown list of languages.  Selecting a language changes the text of the page to translated values.  The automation works correctly in Firefox; selecting the dropdown value triggers the page reload with the new text.  I can see the selection happen in IE but no page reload.  I have tried firing onclick, onselect(which gets an invalid argument exception), onchange with no luck.  The Ajax call in question looks like this:

```
$('#localeSelect').change(function() {
            if ($('#localeSelect').val() != "") {
                var url = $('#localeSelect').val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    success: function(){
                        window.location.reload();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

I don't get any Watir errors running the test, it just refuses to reload.  I've run into this problem with IE a lot, and I am wondering if I can call the window.location.reload() directly if there is no other solution.

Thanks in advance,
Sabrina

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have to find which JavaScript event to fire: [How to find out which JavaScript events fired?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787555/how-to-find-out-which-javascript-events-fired)

Comment: Now that's a highly useful tool to know about.  Thanks!

Comment: unfortunately, info obtained still not solving problem. I see events popupshowing, focus, click(selecting the value),popuphiding, a GET call that includes the language selection info, and then a change event.  Directly invoking fire_event on popupshowing is apparently not allowed (get a WIN32OLE runtime error) and everything else does not activate the dropdown display or trigger the page reload.